# How to check whether a JavaScript function exists in Parent Window

Tags: javascript

I am currently working on a web forms application. I have Javascript function [e.g  `HideWaitMessage()` ] in the parent window. I use `window.parent.HideWaitMessage()` from child window to access this and it works as expected.

However, in order to avoid errors, I wanted to verify whether the function does exist in the parent window. Please advise on how I can achieve this.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried checking

```
if (typeof window.parent.HideWaitMessage === 'function') {
// sage to use
}
```

Comment: Thanks that did the trick.

Answer (score 1):

I would use the following protection

```
window.parent && typeof window.parent.HideWaitMessage === 'function'
```

Comment: In what circumstances would `window` be falsy?

Comment: @nnnnnn Nodejs or some specific environment?

Comment: In Node.js wouldn't `window` not be defined at all and thus result in a reference error? Anyway, I think it's fairly clear the OP is describing a browser-based scenario.

Comment: @nnnnnn You are right, thanks...

Comment: Yes that solved it Thanks